# Using Cucumber with Java, can I use 2 ServiceHooks classes in a project?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, cucumber, cucumber-java

I'd like to create a test framework using Cucumber and Java that has both UI and API capabilities.
Can I use a ServiceHooks class with an @Before annotation to run some prerequisites for UI tests and another ServiceHooks class with another @Before annotation to run some prerequisites before the API tests?

If yes, how would I tell cucumber which one to use when a test is run?

This is the TestRunner class:

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.SnippetType;
import cucumber.api.testng.CucumberFeatureWrapper;
import cucumber.api.testng.PickleEventWrapper;
import cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/resources/features",
        glue = {"stepDefs"}, // this is a package in which I have the ServiceHooks class and the StepDefinitions class
        snippets = SnippetType.CAMELCASE,
        tags = {"not @Ignore"}
       ,
        plugin = {
                "pretty",
                "html:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber-pretty",
                "json:target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json",
                "rerun:target/cucumber-reports/rerun.txt"
        }


        )
public class TestRunner {
    private TestNGCucumberRunner testNGCucumberRunner;

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setUpClass() throws Exception {
        testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());
    }

    @Test(groups = "cucumber", description = "Runs Cucumber Feature", dataProvider = "scenarios")
    public void scenario(PickleEventWrapper pickleEvent, CucumberFeatureWrapper cucumberFeature) throws Throwable {
        testNGCucumberRunner.runScenario(pickleEvent.getPickleEvent());
    }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        return testNGCucumberRunner.provideScenarios();
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDownClass() throws Exception {
        testNGCucumberRunner.finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The service  hook class must be in the glue at cucumber options. you have to pass UI or API as argument and set glue class path accordingly. These can be just hard coded runner class ( just like @tag value) or pass it as command line arguments.

```
public class runner()
{
public static String testPath;
private final string API = "<path to API service hook>";
private final string UI = "<path to UI service hook>";
public static String testPath;
public static void main ( String args[])
{

if(args.length >1)
{
testPath = args[0]
}
else
{
String testPath = API ; //or UI
}
Main.main(new String[]{<Pass cucumber parameters>, "-g" ,testPath});

}
```

Comment: I have added the TestRunner class to the question. Are you saying that in the @CucumberOptions the glue property can point to the location of 2 different ServiceHooks classes? If yes, how? I am running the test class and the TestRunner class directly from the IntelliJ IDE UI. I'm having a bit of trouble relating to what you are explaining. Can you please show me how what you said would apply to my TestRunner class?

Comment: @JustNatural i am using main Method approach to run my features. This also helps me in running these tests through command line/ CI tools. I think in your case, you will not be able to initialize the glue path on the runner class.  However you should be able to achive this by passing the parameter from your testng xml. You can control the flow on the serviceHooks based on the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so using tagged hooks and tagging your features or scenarios with the relevant tags, for instance `@api` and `@browser`.

From the [Cucumber docs on tagged hooks](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#tagged-hooks):
"Hooks can be conditionally selected for execution based on the tags of the scenario. To run a particular hook only for certain scenarios, you can associate a Before or After Hook with a tag expression.

nnotated method style:

```
@After("@browser and not @headless")
public void doSomethingAfter(Scenario scenario){
}
```

Lambda style:

```
After("@browser and not @headless", (Scenario scenario) -> {
});
```

"